# Problems with cout ( C++)

Tags: c++, cout

I am having the hardest time figuring out what is wrong here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

double fact(double);
double sinTaylor(double);
double cosTaylor(double);

int main()
{
    double number, sineOfnumber, cosineOfnumber;

    cout << "Enter a number, then I will calculate the sine and cosine of this number" << endl;

    cin >> number;

    sineOfnumber = sinTaylor(number);
    cosineOfnumber = cosTaylor(number);

    cout << fixed << endl;
    cout << cosineOfnumber << endl;
    cout << sineOfnumber << endl;

    return 0;
}

double fact(double n)
{
    double product = 1;
    while(n > 1)
     product *= n--;
    return product;
}

double sinTaylor(double x)
{
    double currentIteration, sumSine;

    for(double n = 0; n < 5; n++)
    {
        currentIteration = pow(-1, n)*pow(x, 2*n+1) / fact(2*n+1);
        sumSine += currentIteration;
    }
    return sumSine;
}

double cosTaylor(double y)
{
    double currentIteration, sumCosine;

    for(double n = 0; n < 5; n++)
    {
        double currentIteration = pow(-1, n)*pow(y, 2*n) / fact(2*n);
        sumCosine += currentIteration;
    }
    return sumCosine;
}
```

Ok, so here's my code. I'm pretty content with it. Except for one thing:
sineOfnumber and cosOfnumber, after the calling of sinTaylor and cosTaylor, will add each other in the following cout line that will print each other.
In other words, if number is equal to lets say, .7853, 1.14 will be printed in the line that is intended to print cosineOfnumber, and sineOfnumber will print the result normally.
Can anyone help me identify why this is? Thank you so much!

Comment: A factorial function with a `double` parameter and a for loop with a `double` counter are both bad signs.

Comment: Yeah I know. Honestly this is really bothering me to death, I seriously cannot make the program do what it's supposed to unless everything is type double. Is this the cause of the incorrect printing of cosineOfnumber though?

Comment: It could be. Is it the `pow` functions giving you a hard time? Just make sure one argument is a double. For example, `pow(-1., n)`

Comment: Tried, didn't work. Still giving me a 1.14 for cosOfnumber. Strangely enough, commenting the line where sineOfnumber lets cosOfnumber print normally. For some reason it's adding both of them together when I print them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you ever initializing the variables sumSine and sumCosine in your functions? They're not guaranteed to start at zero, so when you call += inside your loop you could be adding computed values to garbage.

Try initializing those two variables to zero and see what happens, as other than that the code seems okay.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much, seriously. As a final request, why is it that this fixed my problem?

Comment: If you don't initialized a variable in C or C++ the compiler isn't compelled to do it for you. Your doubles were just filled with whatever garbage was on the stack at the time your function was called. That's the best description I can give without going super-technical. (Can you mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem?)

Comment: @user2063355, Because it could start off with a value of 2 or 768 or 1565626 if uninitialized. In this case, it probably obtained the value left on the stack from the other function call, which is why it seemed like the two were added.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I marked it correct, and thanks for helping out a relatively new guy to c++. Hang ups like this tend to get me the most.

Comment: Not a problem! It gets us all when we start using new languages.

Answer (score 0):

The series for the sine is (sorry for the LaTeX):

```
sin(x) = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{x^{2 n + 1}}{(2 n + 1)!}
```

If you look, given term t_{2 n + 1} you can compute term t_{2 n + 3} as

```
t_{2 n + 3} = t_{2 n + 1} * \frac{x^2}{(2 n + 2)(2 n + 3)}
```

So, given a term you can compute the next one easily. If you look at the series for the cosine, it is similar. The resulting program is more efficient (no recomputing factorials) and might be more precise. When adding up floating point numbers, it is more precise to add them from smallest to largest, but I doubt that will make a difference here.